# create hastag system like twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a hastag system like the system of twitter. I already have develop some code but i still have some problems.

in this link you can see the code: https://jsfiddle.net/prd3uf8r/1/

html

```
<form id="newPost">
    <div id="tagSystem"
         placeholder="Your Post..."
         style="width: 100%; height: 150px; padding: 5px 7px; overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid black"
         contenteditable="true"
         value=""></div>
    <input type="submit" value="comment" class="btn" id="btn-create" />
</form>
```

1º issue. if the user at the end create a hashtag and don't press the space, I will submit an input. I need to know how to "autoclick" in space when user submit the form.

```
 $("#newPost").on('submit', function(){
    // auto press space key to create the last tag if the user dont press the key
})
```

2º if the user try to edit a tag, the text after user edit the tag and press space key, should be in normal color, and not in blue.

3º sometimes if user type fast, the tag can have a space, and i don't want to allow that.

4ª finally somne times if i create tags and delete all the text, the when user click in the # the system don't work

Thanks for your time and your help

Comment: I would probably analyze the text area using the onchange and add the tags that way, meaning scan all of the text and add your tags. There are a lot issues will have this way. For example, if I use my mouse to select the # and delete it then the word still thinks it is a tag.

Comment: The problem in the textarea you can't style the text.. and I need to give some color to the text. But your think is correct. I don't realize that. Thanks for the help

Comment: change `$("#tagSystem").on("keyup"` to `$("#tagSystem").on("input"` to solve your problem and the one mentioned by @Gremash

Comment: Hi Dandavis. the problem is the same. i have update the example ( [link](https://jsfiddle.net/prd3uf8r/2/) ) and like you can see in the code, when user click in the btn, will copy the input box without any value